# .animate scroll nested div

Tags: jquery, html, css, nested

I am setting up a site that has parallaxing nested `div`s and I'm attempting to animate the scroll to each div. The problem im running into is that most .animate scrollto's I'm finding are relying on the `html`,`body` which is where I think I'm having a problem since the scrolling happens to the parent `div` vs. the body of the page. I've set up a fiddle that gives the basic outline of the site with simple anchor tags that take you to the next nested div/section. I am attempting to animate the scroll between each one vs. jumping to the next anchor. Can someone point me in the right direction? [Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/patricktrefry/nd76L8ch/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function scrollToAnchor(group1) {
            var aTag = $("a[name='" + group1 + "']");
            $('parent-container').animate({
                scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
        $("#group1").click(function() {
            scrollToAnchor('#group2');
        });

        function scrollToAnchor(group2) {
            var aTag = $("a[name='" + group2 + "']");
            $('parent-container').animate({
                scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
        $("#group2").click(function() {
            scrollToAnchor('#group3');
        });

        function scrollToAnchor(group3) {
            var aTag = $("a[name='" + group3 + "']");
            $('parent-container').animate({
                scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
        $("#group3").click(function() {
            scrollToAnchor('#group4');
        });

        function scrollToAnchor(group4) {
            var aTag = $("a[name='" + group4 + "']");
            $('parent-container').animate({
                scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
            }, 'slow');
        }
        $("#group4").click(function() {
            scrollToAnchor('#group1');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent-container" class="master-wrap"> // overflow:scroll, 100vh
            <div id="group1" class="wrap"> //100vh
                <h1>Some Title Here - box1</h1>
                <p>some content here.</p>
                <a href="#group2" class="next_button">&#8595;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="group2" class="wrap"> //100vh
                <h1>Some Title Here - box3</h1>
                <p>some content here</p>
                <a href="#group3" class="next_button">&darr;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="group3" class="wrap"> //100vh
                <a href="#group4" class="next_button">&darr;</a>
                <h1>Some Title Here - box3</h1>
                <p>some content here</p>
            </div>
            <div id="group4" class="wrap"> //100vh
                <h1>Some Title Here - box4</h1>
                <p>some content here</p>
                <a href="#group1" class="next_button">&#8593;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me:

```
$( function () {
            $( 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])' ).click( function () {
                if ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//, '' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//, '' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) {
                    var target = $( this.hash );
                    target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice( 1 ) + ']' );
                    if ( target.length ) {
                        $( '.parallax' ).animate( {
                            scrollTop: $( '.parallax' ).scrollTop() + target.offset().top
                        }, 1500 );
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this doing a more generic solution, where you use a [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute to indicate which element should be scrolled to upon clicking the element.

For instance, `<div data-scroll-to="other-element">···</div>` would scroll to the element with id `other-element`. Please see the following for a working example:

```js
$('[data-scroll-to]').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $("#" + $(event.target).data('scroll-to'))
  var offset = target.offset().top
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 'slow')

})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" data-scroll-to="box2" class="box">
  Box 1 > Box 2
</div>

<div id="box2" data-scroll-to="box3" class="box">
  Box 2 > Box 3
</div>

<div id="box3" data-scroll-to="box1" class="box">
  Box 3 > Box 1
</div>
```

Comment: This works in fiddle - however I cant seem to get it to work on my site. Im putting together a custom wp site based off of the HTML5Blank theme and custom front-page based off of this: https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/ . Here is the site im working on with your answer implimented but not functional: https://www.phxdesignguy.gq/

Comment: Im sorry to hear that the code isn't working on your site. You probably have something conflicting with it. It's hard to say what's wrong without diving too much into the link you provided, which is out of scope for stackoverflow, accordingly to their guidelines. However, I did a little inspection, and it seems that .animate is not working, e.g. try adding the following in the web inspector: `jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 200}, 'slow')`. I suspect it's the parallax plugin you're using who's causing you trouble.

Comment: the parallax is css driven, however I do have a .animate plugin installed which could be causing some conflict. I appreciate your assistance though.